# Confusion with terminology of Green's function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem 
[image]

The definition I have for Green's function is

The ${\bf Green's \; function}$ $G(x)$ for the operator $-\Delta$ and the domain $D$ at $x_0 \in D$ is a function defined for $x \in D$ that satisfies

1. G(x) possesses continuous second derivatives and $\Delta G=0$ in $D$, except at the point $x=x_0$.
2. $G(x) =0$ for $x \in \partial D$.
3. The function $G(x) + \dfrac{1}{4 \pi |x-x_0|}$ is finite at $x_0$ and has continuous second derivatives everywhere and is harmonic at $x_0$.

My confusion is that this problem is asking for green's function on the entire space, but what is the operator here? The wording of the problem is confusing a little bit.

Comment: $\Delta$  is the [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator). For $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose metric is flat, $\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$.

Comment: Do you know Laplace's equation? If you do, the hint tells you how to complete the problem. Note that for a spherically symmetrical function in spherical coordinates, the Laplacian becomes $\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \right)$. The function which solves $\nabla^2 f = 0$ is the Green's function at $0$.

Comment: what is the unit flux?